# pdftk wont merge multiple large pdfs

Tags: terminal, pdftk

I just got a bunch of pdf files back from a freedom of information request. I'd like to have them in one large file as opposed to 92 separate files (~12.3GB) so I can search all the documents for what I need to get.

I've tried using Acrobat (crashed or file size too big for operation), preview (unresponsive/crashed) and pdftk (just didn't do anything).

I'm running MacOS 10.12.6 on the iMac terminal I'm using.

Here's what I punched into Terminal after changing my directory.

```
pdftk *.pdf cat output newfile.pdf
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "pdftk just didn't do anything"? Did it print any error messages? Did you try running in verbose mode? Did it exit? If so, with status 0 or nonzero? Immediately or after some time?

Comment: Also, do you really need to work with one huge document? Maybe a tool such as `pdfgrep` would be enough.